# Minecraft doesn't respond to Response packet

Tags: java, network-programming, minecraft, packets

I'm creating my own server-software from scratch using [this](https://github.com/TorchPowered/network) library.

Right now the client sends the server a Handshake packet, the server decodes it using a Handshake Codec and returns with a Response message encoded with a Response Codec, however I never get a Ping packet.

Here is my code for encoding the Response message to the server.

```
public class ResponseCodec implements Codec<ResponseMessage> {
@Override
public ResponseMessage decode(DataInputStream dataInputStream) {
    String json = ByteUtilities.readUTF8(dataInputStream);
    return new ResponseMessage(json);
}

@Override
public DataOutputStream encode(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, ResponseMessage responseMessage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream packetArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream packetStream = new DataOutputStream(packetArray);
    ByteUtilities.writeVarInt(packetStream, 0x00);
    ByteUtilities.writeUTF8(packetStream, responseMessage.getJson());
    ByteUtilities.writeVarInt(dataOutputStream, packetArray.toByteArray().length);
    try {
        dataOutputStream.write(packetArray.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataOutputStream;
}
}
```

And here is my connection listener:

```
server.setConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnect(Socket socket, DataInputStream dataInputStream) throws Exception {
            //header
            int packetSize = ByteUtilities.readVarInt(dataInputStream);
            int packetId = ByteUtilities.readVarInt(dataInputStream);

            // writing handlers
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream socketStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);

            //identification
            if(packetId == 0x00) {
                // decode
                HandshakeCodec codec = new HandshakeCodec();
                HandshakeMessage message = codec.decode(dataInputStream);
                if(!(message.getProtocolVersion() == 47)) {
                    System.out.println("Client " + message.getAddress() + ":" + message.getPort() + " seems to have a incompatible client.");
                }
                ResponseCodec responseCodec = new ResponseCodec();
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader formatReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ResponseFormat.txt")));
                String line = formatReader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append(System.lineSeparator());
                    line = formatReader.readLine();
                }
                String everything = text.toString();
                String accountedWithVariables = everything
                        .replaceAll("MAX_PLAYERS", "" + maxPlayers)
                        .replaceAll("ONLINE_PLAYERS", "" + BasicServer.onlinePlayers)
                        .replaceAll("MOTD", motd);
                ResponseMessage responseMessage = new ResponseMessage(accountedWithVariables);
                responseCodec.encode(socketStream, responseMessage);
            }

            if(packetId == 0x01) {
                long pingLong = dataInputStream.readLong();
                PongCodec codec = new PongCodec();
                PongMessage message = new PongMessage(pingLong);
                codec.encode(socketStream, message);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCaughtException(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Main thread has recieved a exception: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Before you go crazy trying to figure this out, it would be worth your time to determine whether or not minecraft is *actually* receiving your packet.  Even if it is a local server, there is potentially a lot of fireware in your way.  Could end up saving you a lot of time.  If you know it is receiving it, then you go through the painstaking work of making sure it is a valid request to the server both in syntax and context.

Comment: By a quick look, it seems like you decoding the packets incorrectly, http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping shows that you should respond with 3 differend packets, but you only have code for 2 differend packets

Comment: @Ferrybig the request packet isn't important. It doesn't contain information.

Comment: @Neil Checking it now.

Comment: I just checked that it has sent the packet.

Comment: @CatSources I'm sure your program sent the packet.  Have you verified that the server received it?  [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is very useful in situations like this.

Comment: @Neil This is the server, not the client. As I said above, the client has sent a handshake packet to the server and the server sent a Response packet in response to the handshake successfully by checking WireShark.

Comment: The usefulness of this exercise is relative.  We're trying to establish whether or not the ping packet is received.  By "server", I mean minecraft server application, not computer.

Comment: @Neil I don't think you understand. This is the server sending a response packet to the client. The client is not responding. By the way, this library can handle these types of things like this [example](https://github.com/TorchPowered/network/blob/master/src/test/java/net/torchpowered/networktest/SendingServer.java), so it cannot be the library's fault.

Comment: I'm not claiming it is the library's fault.  Rather the inverse.  Systems tend to get in the way often in these types of discussions.  Whether it is the client or the server is somewhat irrelevant.  You simply need to know if it arrived at the destination.

Comment: It arrived at it's destination.